# Is it stealing to eavesdrop?

Tags: halacha, talmud-bavli, agada-stories-legends, gezel-stealing, masechet-yoma

According to bYoma 35b Hillel was denied entrance to a Beit Midrash which required students to pay for admission. Hillel instead climbed to the skylight and listened to the discussion for free. I would like to know if such behavior is halachically permissible. Meaning, if for whatever reason attending a Torah class or study hall costs money and a person can find a way to access that teaching without paying for it, is that person in violation of halacha in any way (stealing or otherwise)?

Comment: Are you allowed to charge for Torah? Or was the fee for the facilities?